# Issue with the __SITE_PATH in MVC framework

Tags: php

I am creating a basic MVC structured CMS in PHP, as a means to learn how MVC works. I have set up all the files, and started working on the login form, however, when I click a button to submit the form into the database, I received the following worning:

```
You don't have permission to access /project/views/admin/<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor=' on this server.
```

I am wondering if the error is in my __SITE_PATH, might be I am referencing in incorrectly.

1.**index.php** file:

```
<?php
/*** error reporting on ***/
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*** define the site path constant ***/
$site_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
define ('__SITE_PATH', $site_path);
//echo __SITE_PATH ;
include 'includes/init.php';

$registry->router = new router($registry); // load the router

$registry->router->setPath (__SITE_PATH . '/controller/'); // set the path to the controllers directory

?>
```

2.**init.php** file (or configuration file):

```
<?php
 //define ('__SITE_PATH', $site_path);
/*** include the controller class ***/
include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'controller_base.class.php';

/*** include the registry class ***/
include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'registry.class.php';

/*** include the router class ***/
include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'router.class.php';

/*** include the template class ***/
include __SITE_PATH . '/application/' . 'template.class.php';


/*** auto load model classes ***/
function __autoload($class_name) {
  $filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
  $file = __SITE_PATH . '/model/' . $filename;

  if (file_exists($file) == false)
  {
    return false;
  }
  include ($file);
}

/*** a new registry object ***/
$registry = new registry;

$db_name = 'project_db';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
  $handler = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=project_db", $username, $password);
 /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
// echo 'Connected to database';

/*** close the database connection ***/
//$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
/*** create the database registry object ***/
$registry->db = $handler;

?>
```

3.**login.php** file directory (project/views/admin/login.php):

```
 <?php 
 // define ('__SITE_PATH', $site_path);
 if(empty( $_POST ) ) {
 ?>
 <section class="container">
 <form id="admin_login" action= "<?php echo __SITE_PATH; ?>login.php" method="post">
    <ul id="login-form">
        <li>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </li>
        <li class="mid-btn">
            <input class="submit btn" type="submit" value="login"/>
        </li>
    </ul> 
    </form> <!-- end of admin-login form -->
    </section> <!-- end of section -->
   <?php 
   }
   else 
   {
     $db_name = 'project_db';
     $hostname = 'localhost';
     $username = 'root';
     $password = '';

     $handler = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=project_db", $username, $password);
     echo 'Connected to database';
     $form = $_POST;
     $username = $form[ 'username' ];
     $password = $form[ 'password' ];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO admins (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
     $query = $handler->prepare( $sql );
     $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password ) );
   }
   ?>
```

4.**router.class.php**:

```
   private function getController() {

    /*** get the route from the url ***/
    $route = (empty($_GET['rt'])) ? '' : $_GET['rt'];

    if (empty($route))
    {
      $route = 'index';
    }
    else
    {
      /*** get the parts of the route ***/
      $parts = explode('/', $route);
      $this->controller = $parts[0];
      if(isset( $parts[1]))
      {
        $this->action = $parts[1];
      }
    }

    if (empty($this->controller))
    {
      $this->controller = 'index';
    }

    /*** Get action ***/
    if (empty($this->action))
    {
      $this->action = 'index';
    }

    /*** set the file path ***/
    $this->file = $this->path .'/'. $this->controller . '.php';
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where that is being called, but it looks like your `/project/views/admin/` path does not have a site path prefix. Presumable the `project` directory is not at the root of your filing system?

Comment: Incidentally, I would drop the double underscores from this constant - that format tends to be reserved for PHP. They will work, of course.

Comment: Why not just use `SITE_PATH`, what's with the `__`

Comment: @halter the project is the root file

Comment: does your router not handle routes then if your calling files like `login.php`?

Comment: it does, i will include router folder

Comment: Are you following a tutorial by Michael Peacock by any chance?

Comment: @Martin Bean, no I am not. My have fixed the issuse

Comment: You should split your **login.php** file. Keep in **views** folder only page rendering files. Make another folder for **post/ajax** files and send the data there. It's more clear and easier for tracking bugs.

Comment: Yes, you should not have any DB code in your login.php file if its a view, or any view code if its supposed to be a controller or model... Also if you are going to make your own autoloader for the sake of learning then you should make it `psr-0` or `psr-4` compliant and structure your project appropriately. That will help you to understand how things should be autloaded.